# Can't get jQuery event to work

Tags: jquery, html

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here but for some reason I can't get the .click() event listed in this jQuery box to work.  Being as this is my first attempt at using jQuery I'm assuming that it's probably a small nuance that I haven't accounted for or a detail that I've over looked.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
  <style>
    #thumbs { padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden; }

    #thumbs img, #largeImage {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .thumbnail {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 6px;
      height: 60%;
      width: 60%;
    }

    #description {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      width: 525px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    #panel { position: relative; }

  </style>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >
      $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
        $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gallery">
      <div id="panel">
        <img id="largeImage" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image2.jpg" />
        <div id="description">First image description</div>
      </div>

      <div id="thumbs">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image2.jpg" alt="1st image     description" />
        <img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image3.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
        <img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image4.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
        <img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image6.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aside: the doctype of XHTML does not allot `<style>` as a child of `<html>`. Only `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<frameset>` are allowed here. Just sayin' for proper markup. In the end, your browser probably does it right automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<html>
<style>
#thumbs { padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
#thumbs img, #largeImage {
border: 1px solid gray;
padding: 4px;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnail {
float: left;
margin-right: 6px;
height: 60%;
width: 60%;
}
#description {
background: black;
color: white;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
padding: 10px 20px;
width: 525px;
margin: 5px;
}
#panel { position: relative; }

</style>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
  $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
  $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">
<div id="panel">
<img id="largeImage" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image2.jpg" />
<div id="description">First image description</div>
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
<img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image2.jpg" alt="1st image     description" />
<img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image3.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
<img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image4.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
<img class="thumbnail" src="C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\Image6.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This actually did not work.  Should I have downloaded the jQuery library?  I assumed that this was done via the src attr in my script tags.  I also am concerned because the load times on this page are considerable and I'm not exactly sure why.  I've been using the same images throughout my site and this page takes literally about 45sec to load.

Comment: I eventually figured out what was going on with the ridiculous load times and the reason I was unable to get my jQuery statement to actually work.  Apparently my  call to the Google CDN to retrieve my jQuery library was timing out.  I downloaded the most recent version from jQuery.com, changed the src, and all of a sudden it was working like a champ.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into document.ready event, Since you are a beginner I would like to tell something about `document.ready` event, Actually the code inside this event will get invoked only after the `DOM got ready`. So that we can `manipulate` it afterwards. Manipulating the DOM before the its ready state will results in error.

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
$('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
$('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
 });

});
```

Read this for full reference : [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: This did not work.  Not sure as I said to the first answer should I have installed the jQuery library?  I assume this was done with the src attr in my script tags.  I also am moderately concerned about the load times of this page. It's taking anywhere from 30sec to 45sec to load into my browser.  Seems very long.